# Windows 8.1 how to dismiss a SettingsFlyout programmatically

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have a Windows 8.1 application.

In that I have a SettingsFlyout in ShowIndependent mode.
Inside the settings flyout I have a List
I want the SettingsFlyout to dismiss on click of any item in the list.

I would be very glad if someone can point me in the right direction to implement it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call [`SettingsFlyout.Hide()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.settingsflyout.hide.aspx):

> By default, the settings flyout is dismissed when the user presses the
>   back button, and is always light-dismissed when the user taps outside
>   of it. In most cases, you will not need to call the Hide method to
>   dismiss the settings flyout.
>
> Calling the Hide method has the same behavior as light dismiss. It
>   always returns the user to your app and closes the settings pane,
>   regardless of whether the settings flyout was opened by calling Show
>   or ShowIndependent.